# Best way to execute a thread after a period of time in android

Tags: android, timer, runnable

I am having a service in my application that puts a runnable (in another java file) in a thread and starts it.
That is working fine for once, but i want it to be repetitive due to a certain period.
I need a good way to handle that. 
Reason why I didn't use the answers to other questions is that I don't want it to repeat infinity nor I know how many times it'll repeat the task. It'll simply stop due to a button click in the UI.

I was thinking of using a loop with a sleep and if statement. But I think that's really bad design for my application. Is there a standard way for doing such thing?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a handler that somehow acts like a timer but I think it is better for your situation.

You initialize it like this:

```
Handler delayhandler = new Handler();
```

Set the time it fires like this (in ms):

```
delayhandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 500);
```

And it calls this:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable()
{   public void run()
    {   // Todo

        // This line is necessary for the next call
        delayhandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}
```

You can also remove the next call with:

```
delayhandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many times I will run it... Timers looks nicer

Comment: Thats the point, with a handler you have to explicitly say that you want to run it again or can just prevent it from running again anytime you want. Timers are messier.

Answer (score 1):

Use a TimerTask and have it execute your thread/method.

http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html - You can use the Cancel() method to stop the TimerTask from executing.

Comment: Java timers run on separate threads, so this is a good approach.  You don't even have to start one yourself.

Comment: I guess this looks promising, but I got stuck in doing restarting the timer after cancelling... I get to error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer was canceled"... then i tried: myTimer.cancel();
    myTimer = new Timer();, but I got the following error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already"... I tried

Answer (score 0):

Use the Timer it will run the thread after a given time period and when you want to stop just stop timer or set it to infinite time period.

Comment: Ok but, can you please provide me with some code or referring for how to set up a timer?